# I can't get a configuration file

Tags: android

**EDIT**

I'm following this tutorial to [Add Analytics to myAndroid App](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)

but when I reach the step where I should get a a configuration file when I go to the page where I should download my `JSON` file it just gives me the spinning downloading circle for a long long time and I can't get the file.

I'm logged in with my Google account.

Is there any other way to get the file?

Comment: `the rotary downloading circle` which - I guess - is your description of an `indeterminate ProgressBar`?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Yes the spinning circle. I left the page open all the day but nothing happened.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I don't know why would someone down vote for this..

Comment: @rootpanthera Yes I shocked when I got down voted! therefore I'm saying "It turned out that it's a common issue" in my answer :)
Thank you for up voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it's a common issue

check out this issue in analytics-issues group [here](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=811).

To solve this problem I followed those steps

1. Go [here](https://console.developers.google.com/project) and sign in with your account.
2. Create a project.
3. Give your project a name.
4. In Use Google APIs click Enable and manage APIs.
5. From Advertising APIs click Analytics API.
6. Click Enable API.
7. if it shows this warning Click "Go to Credentials" if not skip to Finally

> This API is enabled, but you can't use it in your project until you
>   create credentials.  Click "Go to Credentials" to do this now
>   (strongly recommended).

1. From the list `Where will you be calling the API from?` select the platform. In my case was Android.
2. Click find out what Credentials I need and see it
3. Click Cancel.
4. Then you will be prompted to create Credentials you need. Create them.

**Finally:**

Now go to this [Link](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=analytics&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fdevguides%2Fcollection%2Fandroid%2Fv4%2Fapp%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Analytics) which in the tutorial to get your `JSON` file

Pick a platform.

Create or choose an app.

Choose service and configure.

Choose or create an account from the dropdown list

Choose Analytics property

Click Enable Analytics services .

If you don't see the big blue button `Generate configuration file` scroll down to see it.

Hit it.

Hit Download google-services.json and voila

You got it.